# Regex character interval with exception

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, ocaml

Say I have an interval with characters `['A'-'Z']`, I want to match every of these characters except the letter `'F'` and I need to do it through the `^` operator. Thus, I don't want to split it into two different intervals.

How can I do it the best way? I want to write something like `['A'-'Z']^'F'` (All characters between A-Z except the letter F). This site can be used as reference: http://regexr.com/

**EDIT:** The relation to ocaml is that I want to define a regular expression of a string literal in ocamllex that starts/ends with a doublequote ( " ) and takes allowed characters in a certain range. Therefore I want to exclude the doublequotes   because it obviously ends the string. (I am not considering escaped characters for the moment)

Comment: Can you give an example of what your trying to match and expected output?

Comment: I don't think it could be done more effectively than splitting the range (`[A-EG-Z]`)

Comment: Do you really  **need** to use ``^``? Because you can use this regex ``/(?!F)[A-Z]/ig``without having to split into different intervals.

Comment: Can you explain the relation to compiler construction? Is this supposed to be a regex accepted by ocamllex?

Comment: The `ocaml` tag is not sufficient. In which context are you intending to use the regex? `ocamllex`, `Str`, `pcre-ocaml`, ... ? There is a wide range of choices here, and the answer will probably heavily depend on which backend you're using.

Comment: If you are using ocamllex, you cannot use http://regexr.com as a reference. ocamllex has a very idiosyncratic regex syntax (including using `_` instead of `.` for a wildcard character).

Comment: @rici I noticed.. thought I could translate the syntax myself once I had the solution in regexr

Comment: @novalain: It's misleading for people trying to answer the question, since it implies that you are looking for a Javascript regex. Many people don't notice the tags; in the case of regexes, you should start the question unambiguously: "Using the ocamllex parser generator, I want to express ... " (For future reference.)

Comment: @rici you are right. I am still a beginner with regular expressions and lexers, At first I thought it was defined in the same way everywhere. I know better now, thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `[^ '"']`? I mean why do you need to restrict the contents of string literals further than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is very rare to find two regular expressions libraries / processors with exactly the same regular expression syntax, it is important to always specify precisely which system you are using.

The tags in the question lead me to believe that you might be using `ocamllex` to build a scanner. In that case, according to the documentation for its [regular expression syntax](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual026.html#htoc145), you could use

```
['A'-'Z'] # 'F'
```

That's loosely based on the syntax used in [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns):

```
[A-Z]{-}[F]
```

Java and Ruby regular expressions include a similar operator with very different syntax:

```
[A-Z&&[^F]]
```

If you are using a regular expression library which includes [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC20) (Perl, Python, [Ecmascript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.6)/C++, and others), you could use one of those:

```
(?!F)[A-Z]
```

Or you could use a positive lookahead assertion combined with a negated character class:

```
(?=[A-Z])[^F]
```

In this simple case, both of those constructions effectively do a conjunction, but lookaround assertions are not really conjunctions. For a regular expression system which does implement a conjunction operator, see, for example, [Ragel](https://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/).

Answer (score 1):

The ocamllex syntax for character set difference is:

`['A'-'Z'] # 'F'`

which is equivalent to

`['A'-'E' 'G'-'Z']`

Answer (score 0):

`(?!F)[A-Z]` or `((?!F)[A-Z])*`

This will match every uppercase character excluding 'F'

Answer (score 0):

The regex below accomplishes what you want using `^` and without splitting into different intervals. It also resambles your original thought (`['A'-'Z']^'F'`).

```
/(?=[A-Z])[^F]/ig
```

If only uppercase letters are allowed simple remove the `i` flag.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eW1eT1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use character class subtraction:

```
[A-Z&&[^F]]
```

The alternative of `[A-EG-Z]` is "OK" for a single exception, but breaks down quickly when there are many exceptions. Consider this succinct expression for consonants (non-vowels):

```
[B-Z&&[^EIOU]]
```

vs this train wreck

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]
```

Comment: That's very cool but afaik it is only available in Java and Ruby